# In unit test: How to override an NGRX selector which is created by entityAdapter.getSelectors()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, ngrx

Assume that our app has a books page.
We are using: Angular, NGRX, jest.

**Some lines of code to give a context (see actual problem below):**

Interfaces of the books page's state:

```ts
export interface Book {
  bookID: string;
  whatever: string;
}

export interface Books extends EntityState<Book> {
  error: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
}

export interface BooksFeature extends RootState {
  books: Books;
  //...
}
```

Added to ngrx store as feature:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('books', booksReducer),
    //...
  ]
```

ngrx entityAdapter is created:

```ts
export const booksAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>({
  selectId: (book: Book): string => book.bookID,
});
```

Create `booksSelector` from `booksAdapter`'s `selectAll`

```ts
const { selectAll, selectTotal } = booksAdapter.getSelectors((state: BooksFeature) => state.books);

export const booksSelector = selectAll;
```

Assign `booksSelector` to the component property: `books$`

```ts
public books$ = this.store.pipe(select(booksSelector));
```

Then the books$ observable is used for many things (eg. `<div *ngIf="(books$ | async).length">`, etc...).

**The goal:** Assume that **I would like to unit test separately if the `books$` observable has always the same value as what the `booksSelector` broadcasts.**

Normally I would do the following in the component's `books.component.spec.ts` file:

General setup for component test:

```ts
//...
describe('BooksComponent', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<BooksComponent>
  let store: MockStore;
  const initialState: RootState = {
    //...
    books: {
      ids: [],
      entities: {},
      error: false,
      loaded: false
    }
  };

  const testBook: Book = {
    bookID: 'bookid_1',
    whatever: 'whatever'
  };

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: BooksComponent,
    providers: [
      provideMockStore({ initialState })
    ],
    imports: [
      StoreModule.forRoot({}),
      detectChanges: false
    ]
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
    store = spectator.inject(MockStore);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
//...
```

**And the important part:**

```ts
//...
  describe('books$', () => {
      it('books$ should have the same value as what booksSelector gives', () => {
        const testBooks: Book[] = [testBook];
        const expected = cold('a', { a: testBooks });

        const mockBooksSelector = store.overrideSelector(booksSelector, testBooks);

        expect(spectator.component.books$).toBeObservable(expected);
      });
      //... Then I would like to use the mockBooksSelector.setResult(...) method too for other test cases
  });
//...
```

**The problem with this is that the `MockStore`'s `overrideSelector` method expects a `Selector` as first parameter, but the `entityAdapter`'s `getSelectors` method returns with a `selectAll` method that has a different type.**

Please let me know how could I replace this test with a proper solution!

Please keep in mind, that the problem is simplified to keep it focused and I'm **not** looking for solutions like these:

- Test instead if the store.pipe is called with the proper select.
- Change the state manually in order to have the wished value given by `booksSelector`.
- Solutions that change things not only in the .spec file. (I mean, if it's really inevitable then OK)

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `booksSelector` to any type:

```js
const mockBooksSelector = store.overrideSelector(booksSelector as any, testBooks)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use feature selector as input to `getSelectors`:

```js
const selectBookFeatureState =
  createFeatureSelector<BooksFeature>('books');

const { selectAll, selectTotal } = booksAdapter.getSelectors(selectBookFeatureState)
```

and if that doesn't work you can try creating selectors like this:

```js
const selectAllBooks = createSelector(
  selectBookFeatureState, 
  selectAll
)

const selectTotalBooks = createSelector(
  selectBookFeatureState, 
  selectTotal
)
```

and use `selectAllBooks` instead `selectAll` and `selectTotalBooks` instead `selectTotal`